# Xamarin and Visual Studio: What are the Differences?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, mono

I'm about to start learning C# using the Head First C# book from O' Reilly. It seems to be a pretty amazing book, however there's a slight problem - I don't have Windows. I found this cool looking IDE Xamarin that I thought would make a good substitute for Visual Studio, however I just want to make sure it won't be a total waste of time to download and install it. Or would either running VS on a Virtual Machine be a better option or on Bootcamp. However with Bootcamp the problem would be my lack of hard disk storage - I own a Mac Air and there's barely 40GB left.

So what are the similarities and differences between the two IDEs. Would it make learning C# using Head First difficult?
Also the reason why I'm not just downloading Xamarin and trying stuff out for myself is because my Internet speed is currently terrible (barely 0.5 megabits per second D:) and I'm too impatient to wait so long :P Plus it would be better if I knew before hand how Xamarin will affect the development of any apps I make.

Comment: I don't think it's likely that it will make any major difference for learning C# - at least not a "total waste of time". It might make following that particular book a bit more difficult, but Xamarin is being used by a lot of professional projects out there.

You could also look into [Visual Studio Code](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/code-vs.aspx). That might be a suitable alternative.

Comment: And because of your "impatience" we should deal with this very basic question you could easily find out yourself? Btw.: 0.5MB /sec? sounds like my current company-restrictions. Go with it.

Comment: @HimBromBeere firstly I never really forced anyone to answer my question. Secondly since I have virtually no way of installing VS I cannot "easily find it out" myself. And also, its 0.5Mbps (megaBITS per second) not MBps, there's a difference. It's basically 8 times slower. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin is basically done to create mobile cross-platform apps using all the mono core code.
But as I know, this IDE permit you to do some of other type of codes (F#, C#, ASP…), so for a beginner this IDE is enough. When you will have more experience, using VS will be better (if Microsoft do not implement new things in Xamarin IDE in the future), because all the integration of the Microsoft environment is amazin in VS.
But for now, with you missing space in your MAC, the easiest solution is Xamarin ! (Care when you will install the Android Package in Xamarin installation)

About Visual Studio Code, I think this IDE is not mature enought to be used for learning...

Answer (score 2):

When it comes down to editors/IDE's, there are a number of cross-platform alternatives. Not all are equally well-equipped.

- **Visual Studio Code** is the new and lightweight IDE from Microsoft. It runs on Electron Shell (basically Github Atom) but is not as powerful as full Visual Studio even though the naming may let it seem so. It is more a code editor with a little extra (like type checking and building).
- **Xamarin Studio** is a quite capable IDE, but is less configurable than Visual Studio. Also, it is focused more on Xamarin development, and less on general C# development.
- **Jetbrains Rider** (codename) is Jetbrains' proven ReSharper extension, wrapped in its proven IntelliJ IDE. It is still in development but will be probably quite similar to Visual Studio in terms of functionality. It won't be free though.

Also, bear in mind that there are multiple runtimes for the same language and that there are differences between the runtimes!

- **.NET (Full) Framework**: this is the reference implementation from Microsoft but only runs on the Windows Platform
- **Core CLR**: this is a Microsoft Supported Cross-platform runtime, but only contains core functionality. You cannot use all the libraries in the full framework on this CLR.
- **Mono**: this is an open-source cross-platform implementation of the full-framework. Obviously, not everything can be ported to all platforms, so there are pieces missing. Also, not all libraries are available.

Also 2, Microsoft has signed an agreement to buy Xamarin. Not sure how the IDE will evolve after the deals goes through.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information! I've got a student licence from Jetbrains so I'll be able to install Rider as soon as it comes out.

Comment: You don't have to wait. If you subscribe to their EAP, you can already download the preview version. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the visual difference is Visual Studio uses .net framework  and Xamarin uses Mono Touch. I prefer to use Xamarin for cross platform app development because of reusability of code and components. Xamarin developer need to know android/ios/windows UI designs and coding logic but coding language is c#.

Note that Xamarin has introduced Xamrin Forms,acts as single UI layer for all platforms but still on initial stage. Good luck!